# CDS published via @OData.publish not visible in /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE

Tags: web-services, odata, abap, cds

Created a CDS view with OData exposure in Eclipse. View activated and working correctly, I can see the SQL View data using se16N. View definition below:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZDDLS_ODATA'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.CompareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'TEST CDS Association II'
@Search.searchable: true
@OData.publish: true
define view ZCDSV_ODATA as select from vbak as soHdr 
association [1..*] to ZCDSV_PROD as _itemprod
on $projection.vbeln = _itemprod.vbeln {
key soHdr.vbeln,
    soHdr.auart,
    _itemprod.posnr,
    _itemprod.matnr,
    _itemprod.arktx,
    _itemprod.mtart,
    _itemprod.mbrsh,
    _itemprod // Make association public
}
where auart = 'ZINT'
```

Next step is supposed to be registering the service via /n/IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE. Here is the problem. Entry (unlike the ones created in SEGW) is not available when pushing the "Add Service" button.

This is not a S4/HANA system (installed products below), could this be a release issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could this be a release issue?

Yes, you are right. Publishing CDS entities as OData is supported [since ABAP AS Netweaver 7.50 SP00](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825e9222e7ad4fe1988c6cc600bda779/7.5.16/en-US/f174bdb7a4984debba918c473da03c18.html).